# How to set a city as selector instead of text-box?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I'm doing a custom Magento development. I need to create a drop-down list for cities field when creating a new order with back end.

Is there an extension for this? Or a clear tutorial which can help me?

New order:

[image: New order]

Comment: you want to have a city dropsdown as per country or simply a list of cities for all countries ?

Comment: Please note that questions asking us to recommend or find extensions or tutorials are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. Please also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions.

Comment: @SunilVerma i need it per country

Comment: @honk Thanks for your note 
iam new at Stack Overflow but i will read "How To Ask" then cusomize my question